# magento 1.9 getting javascript error while customer edit

Tags: php, magento

when i am going to view customer detail customer > manager customer > Edit

i get below javascript alert

**error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent(): 
event name: address_country_changed**

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting this error as well and was able to fix it. Below is how I figured it out.

- Open up eav_attribute table through PHPMyAdmin
- Find postcode attribute_code and click edit
- Change is_required from 0 to 1
- Then click go